# How do I set a property on self in Xaml if self is a ContentPage

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

So if I create a new ContentPage in Xaml and then create a property in
the code behind. How can I set that property if self presents itself as
a ContentPage and not as my new typed ContentPage? Some sort of cast?

I know it seems like a newbe question, but today I'm drawing a blank.

e.g. Super simplified.

```
<ContentPage xaml:Class="MyNamespace.MyClass">
  <Myproperty on MyClass>  <!-- this property won't exists for ContentPage -->
    value
  <Myproperty>
  </ContentPage>
```

Comment: Do you want to create custom control? If yes, you can take a look **ContentView** and **BindableProperty**, this is an article that you can take a look:[Xamarin.Forms ContentView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/contentview)

Comment: No @Cherry Bu, I just simply want set the value. See the comment in my code example above. Myproperty is a property in the code behind but won't show up in the xaml because it's in the code behind in MyClass but not in ContentPage class. Ignore the "on MyClass" in the tag. It's just there for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: I figured it out myself. I created an attached property and used it on the ContentPage.

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your problem, please remember to mark your reply as answer, it is beneficial to others to find this answer,thanks.